# where can I find my iOS app's "registered URL"

Tags: ios

I need the registered URL for an app I am working with. I tried this tutorial pointed to in this question.
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

However this did not work and went into the error. The apps name I am trying to open is UCLA Library. I am also working on the UCLA Library and I have access to it. However i never dealt with the registered URL before.

Is there a setting in xcode or a place in project where I can find what the URL is.
Also if there is a special way to deal with caps and spaces in the name too?

Comment: The URL scheme is kept in the plist... You're trying to find the url scheme of the app you're currently working on? Or of a different app?

Answer (score 0):

In that tutorial: **Step 5: Register the Custom URL Scheme** URL types registered in info.plist. Also you can find them in the bottom of **info** tab of your target properties.